# argv[2] value not passing properly from cmd

Tags: c, program-entry-point, argv

I'm having a problem with this code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define N 20

int main( int argc , char * argv[])
{
int giorno , mese , anno , metri , primo_g = 31, primo_m = 12, primo_a = 3000, i = 0 ;
char tipo , destinazione [N+1] ;
float km_arrivo = 0 , costo_tot = 0 ;
FILE * fdati;

if(argc != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr ,"Errore nella linea di comando\n");
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
}

if ((fdati = fopen ("viaggi.dat", "r")) == NULL ) {
    fprintf(stderr ,"Errore nell'apertura del file\n");
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
}

while ((fscanf(fdati , "%s %d/%d/%d %d %c" , destinazione , &giorno , &mese , &anno , &metri , &tipo))!= EOF){
    if (strcmp (argv[2],destinazione) == 0 ) {
        if((tipo == 'R')||(tipo =='r')){
            i++;
            km_arrivo = km_arrivo + (float)(metri/1000) ;
            costo_tot = (i*5) + 0.10 * (km_arrivo);
        }
    }
    if ((anno<primo_a)||((anno==primo_a)&&(mese<primo_m))||((anno==primo_a)&&(mese==primo_m)&&(giorno<primo_g))){
        primo_a= anno;
        primo_m = mese;
        primo_g = giorno;
    }
}
if (fclose(fdati) != 0 ){
    fprintf(stderr , "Errore nella chiusura del file\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

printf("Chilometri da %s: %.2f\n", argv[2] , km_arrivo);
printf("Data primo viaggio : %d/%d/%d\n", primo_g , primo_m , primo_a);
printf("Il costo totale dei viaggia da torino : €%.2f", costo_tot);
exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Viaggi.dat contains :

```
torino 22/01/2011 120000 A
milano 01/03/2011 80000 R
genova 03/06/2011 100000 A
bologna 01/02/2011 100000 A
torino 15/01/2011 120000 R
milano 20/01/2011 80000 R
torino 01/01/2011 80000 A
torino 22/01/2011 80000 R
```

The problem is that when i run the program from cmd and i write the value of argv[2] (e.g "Torino") it tells me that the program stoped working . If i run the program without writing the value of argv[2] it runs good and the stderr message appears.

Thank you in advance,

Regards.

EDIT : I changed argv[2] to argv[1] but I'm still having the same error.

I'm running it from cmd , like this :

C:\Users\HP G6\Desktop\fasdb\bin\Debug>fasdb.exe torino

Comment: `if(argc != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr ,"Errore nella linea di comando: %d\n", argc);
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
}`  .. It's dark and we're wearing sunglasses ...
`

Comment: You need to run your program in a debugger. It will stop when the program crashes, and let you see and walk the function call stack so you can locate where the crash happened in your code. When in the debugger you will also be able to examine variables and see their values.

Comment: you have to change argv[2] into argv[1] it is the only problem, this error is present two times in your code

Comment: Check if `fscanf` is working properly. Use `printf` to see value of `destinazione`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I just tried it in the debugger and it runs good. So the problem is when i run it from cmd. Could the proble be in my laptop ?

Comment: Debuggers clears local variables (i.e. sets them to zero or `NULL`), so when a program runs fine in a debugger it could mean you have an uninitialized local pointer variable that you dereference if it's not `NULL`. Since you check if it's `NULL` it will work when in the debugger because the debugger initializes it to `NULL` for you, but when *not* running in the debugger it will have a random non-null value.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Ah that's why :) I'll keep it in mind and try to search for the error. Thank you for the explanation :)

Answer (score 3):

Remember that `argc` is the number of entries in the `argv` array, and so if `argc` is `2` then you have only indexes `0` and `1` in the `argv` array. For you to use `argv[2]` then `argc` must be `3`.

`argv[argc]` will *always* be `NULL`.

Comment: You mean argv[argc]!! :-)

Comment: @nishant Yes indeed I do! :)

Comment: Yeah i came back to tell that I noticed this error and i changed it but it still gives me error :S

Comment: @user2425899 If it's still the same error, then you should update the question with this information (and you might also want to run your program in a debugger). If it's another problem then you might post a new question about that.

Comment: Well, what happens after you changed it? Your original error should have been fixed right?

Comment: Nope. I run it as i wrote in the post (EDIT part) but I'm still having the same error.

Comment: @user2425899: Did you correct the mistake at **both** places?

Comment: Yes both in strcmp and in the printf :)

Comment: @user2425899: Works here without issues.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to *Joachim Pileborg* (as he already posted before me)

Do remember that indexing starts from 0 in C, so argv[2] is the second string after your program name i.e. if you execute this statement:

`prog_name arg1 arg2`

then

`argv[0] = prog_name`
`argv[1] = arg1`
`argv[2] = arg2`

Also **post your command line statement** you are using to execute the program

Comment: C:\Users\HP G6\Desktop\Fasdb\bin\Debug>fasdb.exe torino

Comment: @user2425899 : Add it to your question statement!! And yes you are doing wrong, see _Joachim Pileborg_'s or my explaination **carefully**.